# Why does my site alert "xssvuln" when I use jqueryui autocomplete?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I implement jqueryui autocomplete on my site but when i load that page, it alerts "xssvuln". but when i tried to run my site on localhost, theres no problem. Can you please help me fix this? And also, im running my site on ipage.

this is my js for autocomplete.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: 'autocompleteCourse.php',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
    var availableCourse = data;
    $( "#course" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableCourse,
        messages: {
            noResults: '',
            results: function() {}
        }
    });
    }
});
```

and this is my php file for autocomplete.

```
include'../utility/sqlcon.php';

$query = mysql_query("select * from autocomplete where input = 'course'") or die          (mysql_error());
while($q=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$courseOptions[] = $q['autoComplete'];
}

echo json_encode($courseOptions);
```

Comment: xssvuln means cross site scripting vulnerability

Comment: also just switched to `PDO` make your life much easier.

Comment: sir can you tell me how to fix this problem? its bothering me for days

Comment: @devZero does switching to pdo will fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that this has little to do with jQueryUI autocomplete, but is probably an indication that someone has hacked your site, albeit in a friendly-warning way.

It's probably a hint that someone's managed to get something into your database like `<script>alert('xssvuln');</script>` as an indication that your site is vulnerable to [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) injection.

Can you have a look at the source code to your live page, and see where the xssvuln alert is coming from? Because I doubt it's the autocomplete, or at least not directly. If it happens when you use the autocomplete, I'd check the search results for whatever you're searching for in your live system to see if they include some Javascript put in there by a hacker, which you're then inserting into your page without proper escaping.

As an example: if your site lets your users add new content, and you simply accept anything they type, and then output it without doing any work to sanitise it -- removing script tags, using functions like [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) during output, etc. -- then you must realise that you're effectively allowing anyone on the internet to *add code to your site*.

One of the ways a hacker will quickly test for XSS vulnerability on a site they're probing is to find an input form on a site, and add script code to it, to see if it's passed through unsanitised. So they might find a comments form, and type:

```
<script>alert('xssvuln');</script>
```

...into it. If they then view the comment page on the site and instead of seeing the *text* `<script>alert('xssvuln');</script>` on the page (as we do here in Stack Overflow, for example) they see a Javascript alert, they know your site is vulnerable.

So, my advice:

- Find out where the alert is coming from. Chances are it's user-submitted content in your database.
- Read up on cross site scripting.
- Protect your inputs and outputs against this kind of Javascript injection.
- Cleanse your database of existing attacks, if necessary.

Comment: i have updated the source code and i removed the javascript part then theres no alert shown. but when i add the js, the page alerts xssvuln again.

Comment: Then what's probably happening is that the Javascript is pulling content containing the scripting from your database. Does the alert pop up as soon as the page is shown, or do you have to use the autocomplete? Can you share the link to the live site with us, so we can have a look? (**NB**: people should bear in mind that the site may contain XSS attacks, of course...) What database queries are being used with the autocomplete? Can you run them through a SQL tool and look at the output, check it for anything suspicious?

Comment: psbpinc.com/career Ah  thanks sir. its clearer for me now. please test it sir hehe.

Comment: Yes. The problem seems to be in your database. For example, if you visit `http://psbpinc.com/career/autocompleteSchool.php`, the source of the autocompletion for the School field, directly in a browser, you'll see that it's outputting a script element in the list of schools. You need to check the code and the underlying data for `autocompleteSchool.php` and figure out how a hacker added that to your database, then protect against it.

Comment: One important point: You can't rely on the front-end to protect against people typing `<` and `>` into the form -- a hacker could just manually send a POST request that *looks* like it's from your form, but contains any data they want to put in. So you need to sanitise your input server-side, not just rely on the front-end.

Comment: ah sir somebody inserts a script to my database. thanks sir for the info

Comment: ah. it new to me that someone can send a post request manually. by the way, again, i updated my source code. i add mysql_real_escape_string on autocomplete field. do you think this will prevent the next xss attacks?

Comment: @AlexCoroza No, I don't think it will prevent the xss attacks, but it will help to avoid SQL injection attacks, which are a different vulnerability. To avoid xss, you should probably use `htmlspecialchars` on the values from the database when outputting them from your autocompleteSchool script, or prevent script tags (or perhaps any angle brackets at all) going into the database in the first place, perhaps with [strip_tags](http://www.php.net/strip_tags), say. Preferably both.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has found a vulnerability in your site, and been generous enough to point it out to you.

It looks like your database has an entry along the lines of:

```
<script>alert('xssvuln');</script>
```

inside it, which is being returned as a result of one of your queries and displayed in your page.

It's not good news to find out this is happening. Your application should really be checking that all data input by users is free of things like  tags and so forth, such that things like this can't happen. Similarly, whenever you display data from your database on a page it's worthwhile running functions that check the data is clean too, because you can never be too sure.

To fix the problem, first I'd hit view source on your live page, and locate where the piece of script is. Once you know that, you can figure out where in your code the script was retrieved, and remove it from your database.

Please don't leave it at that, though. This hacker has highlighted an important vulnerability in your site that someone could easily exploit to do far more damaging things than bringing up an alert message.

Basically, whenever you are displaying text from your database to the user, be sure to wrap it in the following function:

```
htmlspecialchars($yourstring);
```

This is not 100% foolproof, but will go a long way towards reducing the likelihood of successful xss attacks on your site.