# How to prevent cross site scripting

Tags: php, security, xss

I have the following form that users fill in:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="POST">
    <table width="100%" border="0"  cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" ><div align="right"><strong>Name:</strong></div></td>
    <td width="75%" ><span id="sprytextfield1">
      <input id="Cname"name="Name" type="text" placeholder="Please fill in your name">
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right"><strong>Email:</strong></div></td>
    <td><span id="sprytextfield2">
    <input id="Cemail"name="email" type="text" placeholder="e.g sales@company.co.uk">
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right"><strong>Phone Number:</strong></div></td>
    <td>
    <input id="Cphone" name="Phone" type="text"placeholder="e.g. 5555-6666666">
    </td>
  </tr> 

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input name="Manufacturer" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_emailProduct['Manufacturer']; ?>">
    <input name="Model" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_emailProduct['Model']; ?>">
    <input name="Color" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_emailProduct['Color']; ?>">
    <input name="price" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_emailProduct['price']; ?>">
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_GET['id']); ?>">
    <input name="insert" id="insert" type="submit" value="Send Request"></td>
  </tr></tr>

</table>
         </form>
```

Once the form is submitted the following happens:

```
if (isset($_POST["insert"])){
    $OK=false;
  $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO Item_intrest (Manufacturer, Model, Color, price, Name, Phone, email) VALUES (:Manufacturer, :Model, :Color, :price, :Name, :Phone, :email)";


  $Result1 = $conn->prepare($insertSQL) or die(errorInfo());
  $Result1->bindParam(':Manufacturer', htmlentities($_POST['Manufacturer']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $Result1->bindParam(':Model', htmlentities($_POST['Model']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Result1->bindParam(':Color', htmlentities($_POST['Color']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Result1->bindParam(':price', htmlentities($_POST['price']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Result1->bindParam(':Name', htmlentities($_POST['Name']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Result1->bindParam(':Phone', htmlentities($_POST['Phone']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Result1->bindParam(':email', htmlentities($_POST['email']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Result1->execute();
$OK = $Result1->rowCount();



/*email to shop */
$emailsubject = 'Product Request';
$webmaster = 'sales@company.co.uk';
/*data collection */
$Name = htmlentities($_POST['Name']);
$email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
$Phone = htmlentities($_POST['Phone']);
$item1 = htmlentities($_POST['Manufacturer']);
$item2 = htmlentities($_POST['Model']);
$item3 = htmlentities($_POST['Color']);
$Price = htmlentities($_POST['price']);

$Body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $Name<br>
Email: $email<br>
Phone: $Phone<br>
Product:$item1, $item2,$item3<br>
Price: $Price<br>
EOD;
    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $succes = mail($webmaster, $emailsubject, $Body, $headers);


if($OK){
  header('Location: /thankyourequest.php?id=' . htmlentities($_GET['id']). '');
  exit;
}else {
    $errorInfo = $Result1->errorInfo();
    if(isset($errorInfo[2])){
        $error = $errorInfo[2];
        }
}
}
```

For some reason when it is scan it returns

```
From: &lt [mailto:&lt] 
Sent: 20 April 2015 10:04
To: sales@company.co.uk
Subject: Product Request



Name: <script>alert("xssvuln")</script>
Email: <script>alert("xssvuln")</script>
Phone: <script>alert("xssvuln")</script>
Product:<script>alert("xssvuln")</script>, <script>alert("xssvuln")</script>,<script>alert("xssvuln")</script>
Price: <script>alert("xssvuln")</script>
```

As you can see I've tried to prevent this with htmlentities how ever that does not seem to be enough.
Any help welcome to prevent this

Comment: Are you sure that they are not filtered? Maybe your email client/browser converts them back to regular characters, but the source is still encoded? (So in that case, they are not executed as Javascript.)

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20466221/why-does-my-site-alert-xssvuln-when-i-use-jqueryui-autocomplete). This might help you

Comment: You do not have a problem, because the it shows the script.
If it did not show the script it would have embedded it in the html instead of showing the entities as text!
You did a good job.

If you want to hide every tag that is entered, use strip_tags() instead of htmlentities (by the way, htmlspecialchars is more appropriate; not all entities need to be encoded for escaping in HTML.)

Comment: You should use htmlspecialchars().

Answer (score 5):

## **Do not attempt to prevent XSS attacks during input. Always escape on output.**

See also: [Stored XSS in Wordpress 4.2 caused by MySQL column truncation](https://klikki.fi/adv/wordpress2.html). Filtering on output would have prevented these conditions.

Instead, what you want to do is just use prepared statements and store the data naked. (You should still **validate** the data of course! Make sure they've given you an email address when you asked for one, etc.)

When you are pulling the data from the database to display on a webpage, that is when you want to filter. And you want to do it like this (assuming you don't need to allow users to provide some HTML):

```
echo htmlentities($row['column'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
```

### Why `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5` and `'UTF-8'`?

I'm assuming your web page is using HTML5 (i.e. `<!DOCTYPE html>`) and your charset is UTF-8 (i.e. in the `<meta>` tag as well as in the HTTP `Content-Type` header). Please adjust if you're using something different for either.

We specify `ENT_QUOTES` to tell `htmlentities()` to escape quote characters (`"` and `'`). This is helpful for situations such as:

```
<input type="text" name="field" value="<?php echo $escaped_value; ?>" />
```

If you failed to specify `ENT_QUOTES` and attacker simply needs to pass `" onload="alert('XSS');` as a value to that form field and, presto! Instant client-side code execution.

We specify `'UTF-8'` so `htmlentities()` knows what character set to work with. The reason we do this is, as [demonstrated against `mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/2224584), an incorrect (especially attacker-controlled) character encoding can defeat string-based escaping strategies.

Note that this will escape **all HTML special characters** and prevent users from supplying any markup. If you need to allow **some** HTML, we outlined [the best strategies for preventing XSS](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know). In a nutshell:

- Using Twig? The below example is safe. Note the use of `{% autoescape %}` blocks for specifying the default strategy, but overriding it with `|e('html')` for `other_variable`:

  ```
  {% autoescape 'html_attr' %}
  <p class="{{ variable }}" id="{{ var_two }}">
      {{ other_variable|e('html') }}
  </p>
  {% endautoescape %}
  ```
- If all else fails, use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org).

Answer (score 1):

this is called security issue. Cross site scripting, you have many methods to avoid it,

[What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

For example if you have a option to input an email address you have to validate it like below:

```
<?php

$email = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

?>
```

If there is a option to enter a string then you ave to validate like below

```
<?php
            $password = trim(filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

?>
```

In your case you have to do something like below

```
$Name = htmlentities($_POST['Name']);
$email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
```

Instead of above, follow filter sanitizing method:

```
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$Name = trim(filter_var($_POST['Name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
```

Comment: or...  `strip_tags` or `htmlentities` ;)