# Extracting data with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, extract

Helo friends, my code:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="name">
  <input type="text" placeholder="email">
  <input type="password" placeholder="pw">
  <button type="button" id="insert">Insert</button>
</form>
```

My JavaScript file:

```
$('#CadAdmin').click(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){ 
        $.post('/require/jp/insert.php',{
            dataUser:$(this).val()
        },function(res){
            alert(res);
        })
    })
});
```

My insert.php file:

```
extract($_POST); 
    print dataUser;
```

Here, its show all data, ok but, I want to get separete data, for ex:

```
//print dataUser
print $name.' '.$email.' '.$pw;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$_POST` variable is an array (see [$_POST on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)). This means you can access the inner content like this `$_POST['index']`.

For you this would mean that you have to use the form input names with `$_POST`. This gives you `$_POST['name']`, `$_POST['email']` and `$_POST['pw']`. These variables contain the input from the form.

Note that just printing/echoing these variables to your website you might have some problems with XSS, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30882324/5914775) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7142085/5914775) (both from other questions) for on how to prevent something like that from happening.

---

### **EDIT (after comment):**

I suggest you to change (or even remove) your javascript code. Because you are using `$('input').each()` you are currently sending **3 separate POST requests** to `/require/jp/insert.php`, this means the data is handled separately. If you were to change that, your inputs do not have a name, that is why `extract()` doesn't work, the data within `$_POST`isn't set to a specific 'variable' to use after `extract()`.

I suggest you change your code to something like this:

(somehtmlpage.html?):

```
<form method="POST" action="/require/jp/insert.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email">
  <input type="password" name="pw" placeholder="pw">
  <input type="submit" id="insert">Insert</input>
</form>
```

(insert.php):

```
extract($_POST); 
print $name.' '.$email.' '.$pw;
```

What this does is exact the same, without javascript (and the 3 POSTs). Since your data is now within the 'same' `$_POST` you can use the names (from the input fields, 'name=....') after extraction.

Comment: thks for answer, I'm trying to make one CRUD on js but I dont know to do it, with the extract($_POST) I would dont have to do just that, create many variables

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the name (not the placeholder) of each input, then serialize the form data before posting it to your insert.php script.

Comment: its ok friend, but to test, I removed attribute name and returns the fileds values ....but returns all values

Answer (score 0):

First, add name attribute to your elements to catch their values after form submit:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name">
```

then you can get those values like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: thks for your help with or without name's attributes in my file js I have ........dataUser:$(this).val()......so  the insert.php is waiting this variable 'dataUser', using extract($_POST) I dont need to declare many variables ex $name = $_POST['name'], etc....my file insert.php is received one array of js