# Angular - how to prevent XSS attacks in RxJs fromEvent?

Tags: javascript, angular, security, rxjs, xss

I often use `fromEvent` method from RxJS. To be honest, I was expecting some magic from Angular, but apparently there is no. How can I prevent XSS attacks while using `fromEvent`?

Code example:

```
<input #myInput />

fromEvent(this.muInput.nativeElement, 'input').pipe(
  tap(inputEvent => this.saveToDatabase(inputEvent.data)
)
```

Comment: `fromEvent()` here has no significance to cross-site scripting. Same precautions when reading input directly from an `<input>` element  also apply here. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30882324/2924577) for preventing XSS.

Comment: Short answer, yes.

Comment: The problem with using nativeDom event is you will lose reference from time to time

Comment: @Fan Cheung - can u elaborate a bit more? Never heard anything about this...

Comment: Thanks for comments. I was expecting such answers, though had a dream Angular sanitizes bad vales for us. So edited question, maybe someone could answer it easier now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your question, use `fromEvent` you get the same output as `valueChanges` in reactive form, in terms of security measure, it is pretty much the same.

```
<input formcontrol="myInput"/>
myInput.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)
```

vs

```
<input #myInput />
fromEvent(this.muInput.nativeElement, 'input').subscribe(console.log)
```

Angular will sanitize the output if you wrap them in expressions curly brace in your view

```
{{ .. }}
```

but it won't sanitize form input, so this is still a valid form input and sanitization still needs to be in place in the server side.

```
<script>alert('kdfkf')</script>
```

I won't recommend use `fromEvent` to handle changes as in most cases you only bind once to a certain element (supposingly in ngOnInit), if that element removed from DOM by`*ngIf`, your event is gone unless you have code to handle rebinding.

this answer might also help 
[Need to insert Script tag in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458346/need-to-insert-script-tag-in-angular-2)

as well as this 
https://angular.io/guide/security